# Cisco 1841 w/ 3x 3g HWIC - Can high utilisation cause disconnect?

Tags: cisco, 3g

It is my experience that when an interface is being overutilised that the queues start to overflow and the device will start dropping packets.

I am currently experiencing difficulties with a cisco 1841 whereby 1 or 2 out of the 3 cards I have in it are disconnecting and it 'appears' to be related to over utilisation.

I would have thought thought that if this was the case that the card would re-dial and reconnect but this is not occurring.

Can anyone shed any light on if overutilisation can cause these cards to disconnect?